# Chat should have distinct "upvote" and "star" features — the right-hand "star board" should be based on upvotes

Tags: feature-request, chat, up-votes, bookmarks, chat-stars

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Chat Feature-Request: Thumbs-Up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96592/chat-feature-request-thumbs-up)

[Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) currently has a [image] button next to each message which, when clicked, causes the message to appear on the right hand side in the "star board" (along with a count of how many people starred the message). It also allows you to revisit the messages you have starred (though this feature is a little hard to find).

Many messages are hilarious, and I think they should be highlighted on the "star board", but I don't want to save them for later. [The messages I want to find again later are a completely different set.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19979/131139)

I propose this should be changed to a combination of the schemes used for **posts** and **comments** on SE sites:

- An **upvote button** should be present next to each message, **as well as a star/favorite button**.
- The "star board" should be **ranked by upvotes**, not stars.
- Starred messages are for you to revisit later — **similar to favorite questions** on SE sites.

Or, as summarized by Shawn in the comments, *rename "star" to "upvote" and introduce a favourite/bookmark feature.*

(Update: I just found out there's a **daily limit** on stars, and a **time limit** after which you can't unstar a message — these limitations should exist on upvotes *but not favorites* in my proposed system!)

Comment: Ok, I dig that. The last time I tired looking for a specific starred chat message, I ended up getting distracted by the sheer insanity of the other messages and forgot what I was looking for.

Comment: I think a better wording for the summary would be "Make _star_ mean _favorite_ (as it does elsewhere on the site) and add an _upvote_ feature."

Comment: @random That question is indeed a similar idea, but I think mine is a more concrete and well-specified/defined proposal... voting to reopen.