# When moving comments to chat, retain comment upvotes as chat upvotes (not stars)

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat, up-votes, chat-stars

I'm proposing to modify chat to include special chat rooms where there are no stars, but upvotes instead. I've read the previous propositions similar to this one where upvotes get converted to stars and every time the rebuttal is "but upvotes aren't start and there are no upvotes in chat". So add them. It's that simple. Just add a `bool` to the code of the room that says this is a migrated comment thread, not a regular chat room and re-skin the stars to look like upvotes.

With all the fuss about chat rooms and revisiting the rules, I think this won't take too much developers' time to implement something that's been in demand for a long time. I don't think I need to bring up the argument about how upvotes/stars help figure out the public opinion (or how they're used not perfectly in line with the rulebook definition).

If you think this is a bad idea, I'd like to hear your reasoning. Also I'd like to read the staff's thought about this.

Comment: Related: [Chat Feature-Request: Thumbs-Up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96592/chat-feature-request-thumbs-up)

Answer (score 7):

No vote up or down from me here, but I can't agree with your assertion that this won't take much dev time. This seems like a non-trivial change. And chat is... let's just say not the highest priority. It takes a lot to get any time spent on chat.

Beyond that, overloading the meaning of the star column in the database isn't great semantically. If the proposal changed to use separate columns and/or tables, well, that's even *more* dev time.

Comment: Keep them as stars in the backend but show the sprite for a comment upvote in the front end. In any case, even if this takes *some* dev time, I don't think this change should be denied based on just that.

Comment: ...why didn't I get a five-minute edit grace period on this post?

Comment: huh weird... maybe because of the other activity on the post at the same time without you reloading the page

Comment: anyway, I don't think the fact that chat is being neglected is even more reason to neglect it and deny any requests for improvement